# How to change the background color of input element in IE11?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have the following HTML code :

```
 <input name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile" style="width: 650px; background-color: rgb(255, 241, 187);" onchange="resetUpload()" type="file">
```

My problem is that on IE11, the background color of the input is not appearing - whereas on Chrome and IE 9 it is working fine. How we can fix that?

Comment: What version of IE? Also, you need to add a `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the top of your document (as demonstrated by the code before my edit).

Comment: On IE 9 it is working fine

Comment: Does setting a value like 'red' work instead of using rgb? Also, try forcing the issue with a meta tag like this: <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<!-- force IE8+ into standards mode -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
etc...

Comment: On my IE11, the input still has the coloured background even if I don't put in the doctype or the x-ua-compatible stuff (that is, it triggers "document mode 5"), so I don't know what goes wrong in the OP's case.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for the benefit of anyone else finding it, I discovered a weird IE11 behaviour which I got around by using the `::selection` pseudo-class.

It appears...and I haven't found anywhere that explains this, just my observations...that IE11 attempts to do something "clever" with the selection colour of text in an input field if you assign a "lighter" colour via CSS (for example #CFE8F5 or #F47B19).

For example, try this Fiddle: [IE11 Link Text Test](https://jsfiddle.net/yogfkuy6/3/).

Try tabbing between the three input fields and see how IE11 inverts the text selection color in the first input field but does the expected thing on the second (no CSS applied) and third (`::selection` pseudo-class applied) input fields.

Hope this helps someone.

Useful link: [Overriding default text selection colour](https://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/)